# Setting buffer length to HLS streams on Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Is there a way to set the buffer length of HLS streams playing on my chromecast receiver app to 100 seconds or more. Lot of people using our app are facing buffering issues. Increasing buffer length would help us prevent the buffering issues even though some of the HLS segments take time to download.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the buffer duration is set to 20 seconds to control the memory required there, so we don't advise increasing that. You can turn on logging and capture a log when you see buffering and open a [ticket](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list) with us and include your log so we can take a look and possibly make suggestions on how you can improve the performance.

Comment: I do not see buffering all the time..It occurs randomly to some of our customers..So wanted to increase the buffer length to 60 seconds, to ensure there is enough segments on client cache to play..So can you guide me on how to change the buffer length from 20 to 60 ?

Comment: we use a styled media receiver for our android and iOS apps and our web player uses JWPlayer's reciever. Is there a way we can optimize for better experience ?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, we do not advise increasing that to 60 seconds. Please provide logs so we can provide further assistance. In addition, any changes of that type would require writing your own custom receiver; you cannot change the Styled receiver.

Comment: we've opened a ticket on the link you've mentioned. the ticket number is 723. @alinaddaf